# MSMQ Adapter Listener in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, listener, msmq

I have one MSMQ-WCF service that is creating a queue and maintains the MSMQ queue service.
Also, I have another WCF Services hosted in WAS, working like a Listener.

As soon as a message arrives in the MSMQ Queue, it should be automatically picked from the queue and the message should be read.

I just wanted to use it MSMQ Listener adapter. Is there any other way to do this? Please let me know.

Comment: If you want to host the service in IIS then this is the way to do it. What problem are you having? Here's the MSDN document. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752246.aspx

Comment: HeyI gone through that link allready. i have not got any idea how My Wcf Service will Know that message has come in Queue go and pick.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? I don't know about you, but knowing how my tools work is secondary to being able to use them.

Comment: i Tried that one also ,but in that i am not able to call the service. i downloded that code and tried also. –

Comment: I don't think you're going to get many answers here unless you can better describe the problem you're having. "Doesn't work" is not a good enough description.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to host the queue listener in a windows service. This way there is no need to involve WAS and all the complicated setup that can involve.